# Rails Routing String Id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Currently I have four "Teams" in my database.

When I go to root/teams/1 I use #show and see the first team, root/teams/2 the second team, and so on...

However, I don't want teams to be identified with and id in the url. How can I route it to use their names instead like so:

root/team/warriors

root/team/knights

etc.

NOTE: Each Team has a :name string in their row.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a slugger. [This](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem *friendly_id* will make the job for you.
For mongo with mongoid i'm using *mongoid-slug*. Now you know which gem to pick. Try to implement a slug everywhere, that will improve you SEO like A LOT.